# How to stub superclass method in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, mocking, ocmock, stubbing

I am writing unit tests of a class. This class (lets say child class) is inherited from some other class (i.e. parent class). In one method of child class, it is calling a method of its parent class using [super someMethod]. I have partially mocked the child class and wanted to stub the parent class method. So when [super someMethod] called instead of going to parent class method it will come to stubbed method in my test class. Can anyone help me with that ?

This is the public interface of class for which i am writing the test case. It is inheriting from device manager.

```
@interface BTDeviceManager : DeviceManager<MGBTDeviceDelegate>

+ (id) sharedInstance;
- (void)startConnection;

@property (nonatomic,weak) id <MGBTDeviceDelegate> deviceDelegate;

@end
```

Device manager has a method called :

```
- (void) startDiscoveryWithServices:(NSArray *)serviceUUIDs
```

I am trying to stub this method which is getting called from BTDeviceManager.

My Test Class is this:

```
 @implementation BTDeviceManagerTest

           - (void)setUp {
                [super setUp];
                deviceManager = [[BTDeviceManager alloc]init];
                deviceManager.deviceManagerDelegate = self;
                deviceManagerMock = OCMPartialMock(deviceManager);
            }

            - (void)testStartConnection
            {
            NSArray *testShaverServiceUUIDs = @[@"C222"];
            //This is how i am trying to stub the superclass method
            OCMStub([deviceManagerMock startDiscoveryWithServices:testShaverServiceUUIDs]).andCall(self, @selector(handleStartDiscoveryWithServices:));
            [deviceManagerMock startConnection];
        }
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you're going to have to do is mock the parent class and stub the method there. So, in your case, you'd be mocking `DeviceManager`, then when the child makes that call it goes to the mock instead.